# Google foo.bar Re-id challenge not accepting my answer

Tags: python

the question is the following :
Commander Lambda has concatenated the prime numbers in a single long string: "2357111317192329...". Now every minion must draw a number from a hat. That number is the starting index in that string of primes, and the minion's new ID number will be the next five digits in the string. So if a minion draws "3", their ID number will be "71113".

Help the Commander assign these IDs by writing a function solution(n) which takes in the starting index n of Lambda's string of all primes, and returns the next five digits in the string. Commander Lambda has a lot of minions, so the value of n will always be between 0 and 10000

my code is :

```
from logging import error


def solution(i):
    try:
        val = int(i)
        Lambda = ""
        Count = 1
        while int(len(Lambda)) < int(i)+10:
            Count += 1
            Occu = 0
            for x in range(Count):
                if (Count % (x+1)) == 0:
                    Occu += 1
            if Occu <= 2 :
                Lambda += str(Count)
             
            
        
        if int(i)>=0 and int(i)<=10000:
            newId = Lambda[int(i):int(i)+5]
            return str(newId)
    
        else:
            return error("Input needs to be a number between 0 and 10 000")
    
    except ValueError:
        return error("Input cannot contain letters")
    

print(solution(0))
print(solution(3))
```

the code needs to pass these two tests and some other hidden tests :
Input:
solution.solution(0)
Output:
23571

Input:
solution.solution(3)
Output:
71113

these are the constraints :
Your code will run inside a Python 2.7.13 sandbox. All tests will be run by calling the solution() function.

Standard libraries are supported except for bz2, crypt, fcntl, mmap, pwd, pyexpat, select, signal, termios, thread, time, unicodedata, zipimport, zlib.

Input/output operations are not allowed.

Your solution must be under 32000 characters in length including new lines and and other non-printing characters.

When i run the program on VS it works but when i try to verify it in foobar it fails all the tests, any idea what i am missing or doing wrong ?

Comment: That code fails when `i > 3`, I think, and although I cannot see an incompatibility, perhaps VSCode is using Python 3 rather than 2.7. Also, your code is very inefficient when finding primes.

Comment: @KenY-N With Python 3.7 "solution(4)" returns "11131“ as expected. Why should it fail (or fail with Python 2.7)?

Comment: @KenY-N i tried making it more efficient by only creating lambda the length it was required instead of creating a 10004 string each time it only create a string the length of i + 10, but i agree its still slow when i is a big number